# SSL Support in Tomcat : Redirect Issue

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl, tomcat5.5

Below is the snippet from server.xml.Connector port for https is 8444 and i have changed the entry in redirect port as well.

```
    <Connector port="8444" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
           maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75"
           enableLookups="false" disableUploadTimeout="true"
           acceptCount="100" scheme="https" secure="true"
           clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS"
           keystoreFile="c:\keystorefile" keystorePass="tom123"
           />


<!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 -->
<Connector port="8009" 
           enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8444" protocol="AJP/1.3" />
```

I am trying to access one jsp through http url and i was expecting that it will redirect to https but i got an error in my firefox browser ie

> Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at 192.168.9.7:8443.

Why it is looking for 8443 instead for port 8444.

Please help ???

Note : If i try to access the jsp from https url with 8444 port directly then i can access the same.

I am using tomcat 5.5.27

It is requested to throw some light on

> Connector port="8009"

this as well.What is the use of this 8009 port.

Answer (score 1):

```
<!-- Define a non-SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8080 -->
<Connector port="8090" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
           maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75"
           enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8444" acceptCount="100"
           connectionTimeout="20000" disableUploadTimeout="true" />
```

Required changes in NON SSL connector.`redirectPort="8444"`

Now running fine.